# This javascript function works fine when i click it one, but does not work when i click it twice

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im working on a small project which includes adding users as friends. So i created an ajax program that deals with showing the status of the users friendship (i.e whether he is a friend of another user or not),and if you're not a friend,you can add him right away. So i made a small button to do the function i mentioned earlier. It works fine as long as i click the button once, but then does not work when i click it twice. can you guys help me out?

```
function addFriend(user) {
userName = user.getAttribute('data-username') ; 
xmlHttp.open("GET",'addFriend.php?user=' + userName,true) ; 
xmlHttp.send() ; 
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        serverResponse = xmlHttp.responseText ;
        alert(serverResponse) ;  
        if(serverResponse = 'FriendHasBeenDeleted') {
            user.innerHTML = 'Not your amigo' ;
            user.className = 'FriendsONno' ;
        }


        if(serverResponse = 'Added') { 
            user.innerHTML = 'Your Amigo' ;
            user.className = 'FriendsONyes' ;
        }       
    } 
    else {

    }
}
```

}

the php file works fine and echoes two things. One is 'FriendHasBeenDeleted' and the other is 'Added' 
But yet, the javascript file does not do anything when the button is clicked twice

Comment: I nothing clicked here...

Comment: also you are using `=` instead of `==`...

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning, not comparing

```
if(serverResponse = 'FriendHasBeenDeleted') 
if(serverResponse = 'Added') {
```

needs to be

```
if(serverResponse === 'FriendHasBeenDeleted') 
if(serverResponse === 'Added') {
```

---

Now another issue is GET requests cache. So when you send up a request to the server the first time it returns a value. When you requests it again, it just reuses that value. Since you are actually updating the Database, you are better off using a POST request. Post requests do not cache.

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't done anything to my problem. it still doesn't change then innerHTML nor the className

Comment: And are you sure that the response is EXACTLY what you are looking for? Any whitespace, extra characters, etc will not be valid check. Add logs and see what it returns. Learn to debug. `console.log(escape(serverResponse));` This is why JSONP is a better response format.

Comment: Yes, I've cross-checked that a couple of times. :/ And I'm running all of this on wamp. Does that play a part in my problem?

Comment: Did you actually use escape...Do you see any `%20`?

Comment: Nope. I even added the alert to check the response i got back from the PHP file

Comment: So if the alert being triggered? Are you getting 200?

Comment: If it is the **xmlHttp.status** you're referring to in the above comment, I've included the IF statement to check that.

Comment: I posted another reason why it would fail.